# Why don’t they scrape/clean the ice with a zamboni after the 3rd period during the playoffs?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl

During the playoffs of NHL hockey, after the 3rd period, they don’t scrape/clean the ice with a zamboni.  I figure this would cause players to perform less efficiently and potentially be dangerous due to the conditions of the ice in OT.  Seeing as there is a longer break between the end of the 3rd and the start of OT in the playoffs than the regular season, why wouldn’t they use a zamboni on the ice? (Especially when they play unlimited OT periods until some scores )

Answer (score 3):

During the regular season, the OT is 5 minutes.   Since it takes 10-15 minutes to resurface the ice, they don’t do it then.   If, after the OT, they go to a shootout, they will resurface directly in front of the nets, avoiding the sides.

During the playoffs, all OT periods are a full 20 minutes, and the ice is resurfaced after every period.